# Accessing Object's Properties by Index

Tags: c#

```
myObject.property1 = value1;
myObject.property2 = value2;
```

I'd like to access the properties by index, like:

```
"myObject.property[0]" = value1;
"myObject.property[1]" = value2;
```

Is it possible to enumerate properties or to do something else ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just wondering

Comment: I strongly suggest that you give better names to your properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate class members through [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this is not something you will want to use to get or set values on a known type in a normal scenario. It's not performant, it's complex to write, not necessarily runtime-safe and a nightmare to read.

Comment: I don't think we can add parameters to a property getter (or setter) in c#. If this is what OP wants, it will require a separate getter method (much like a Java getter) and not a C# style property.

Comment: Ah, that's right my apologies. I'm a former VB programmer which was just recently converted. :) I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose a list inside your class, you can do it:

```
class MyClass {
    public List<object> property { get; private set; }
    public MyClass() {
        property = new List<object>(100);
    }
}

...

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.property[0] = 1;
myObj.property[1] = "hello";
```

This is not a good idea though.  It's usually much better to expose different typed parameters with names, since the compiler can help you avoid mistakes and the code will be much easier to maintain.